# BuddyPress - Ordering Member Directory - Looking for a definitive answer

Tags: wordpress, themes, buddypress

Anybody still using BuddyPress out there? I have a legacy client that would like to reorder the member directory by alphabetical (last name). After spending hours looking on stack and the BP support blog none of these solutions work. Please help!

Here are the requirements:

- This modification is intended for the default members directory assigned in the admin config -> BuddyPress Settings -> Pages -> Directories -> Members
- Default order on member directory should be ordered by last name / alphabetical (why the F* would alphabetical by first name be the
  default in BP?)
- "Order By" menu on group directory should default to "Alphabetical"
- "Order By" menu options should be re-ordered to display "Alphabetical" first
- Increase default number of members displayed on each page
- Paging needs to work
- Other sort options need to work
- Solution needs to avoid modifying core BP files (preferably through child theme functions.php)
- Solution should not require additional plugins

I'll post, test and curate any solutions proposed.

Thanks for your assistance Stack pros!

S.